# Unsorted ArraysList in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am trying to generate a list with random objects at refresh. Now when I use this, it is shown "object Object" on the list below, but it doesn't generate a new list.

```js
var products = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  price: 1.00
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  price: 1.20
}, {
  name: 'Lemon',
  price: 1.10
}];

document.write(products[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);
```

```html
<ul class="products">
  <li>Apple: $1.00</li>
  <li>Orange: $1.20</li>
  <li>Lemon: $1.10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The elements of `products` are objects, not strings. What do you expect to be shown? What kind of new list are you expecting to generate?

Comment: That list from below with "Apple: $1.00","Orange: $1.20","Lemon: $1.10" to regenerate the order of this at rfreshing page

Comment: You need to write HTML, or use DOM modification functions, if you want to change the `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object = products[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
document.write(object.name + ': ' + object.price);
```

Now, for fun part: how to display whoe list in random order. First I will copy your array, then will use a mixin function, and in the end will display it. This function can be done in many ways.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var newArr = shuffle(products.slice(0)); // will shuffle copy of your array (optional)
for (var i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
   document.write(newArr[i].name + ': ' + newArr[i].price);
}
```

A much better solution would be to create an array of indexes. And each time you will call a method that will select a random index, then you will display it. After it you will remove it from index array, so that index array will get smaller each time you display a record. At the end it will be empty, and your function will end.

Comment: So you need to shuffle the list? Show all elements but in random order yes?

Comment: exatly that I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Because `document.write` is expecting a string but you're passing it an array object.

You could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like so:

```js
 var products = [{
    name: 'Apple',
    price: 1.00
}, {
    name: 'Orange',
    price: 1.20
}, {
    name: 'Lemon',
    price: 1.10
}];

document.write(JSON.stringify(products[Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 )]));
```

Comment: Try snipplets! They are awesome :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @k0pernikus Thanks! (been a while since I've posted so had no idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `document.write` statement in a `JSON.stringify` which will stringify the object into a printable string:

```
document.write (JSON.stringify(products[Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 )]));
```